# angularjs: directive and ng-repeat add extra div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got the directive as follows:

```
app.directive("photos", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            "photoid": "@",
            "scrollable": "@",
            "size": "@",
            "list": "=",
            "inline": "@",
            "extension": "@"
        },
        template: 
        '<div id="photos{{photoid}}" class="scroller" ng-class="[{{scrollable}}]" ng-style="{display:list.length==1?\'inline-block\':\'block\', width: list.length==1?\'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\':\'auto\', height: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\'}">\n\
            length={{list.length}}\n\
            <div ng-repeat="p in list"\n\
                ng-style="{\'background-image\': \'url({{p.file}}.thumb.{{extension}})\', width: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\', height: \'{{size?size:\'171px\'}}\'}"\n\
                ng-click="$parent.$parent.openPopoverImageViewer(\'#photos{{photoid}}\', {{$index}})">\n\
                <div>{{p.text}}</div>\n\
            </div>\n\
        <div>'
    };
});
```

I invoke it twice as follows:

```
    <h2 class="tintColor">Impact de la densité sur le rendement grain d'une variété</h2>
    <photos photoid="ImpactPrecoce"     list="[{file:'rsc/drive/4-Semis/d-ChoixDeLaDensite/ImpactPrecoce'}]"        size="256px" extension="png"></photos>
    <photos photoid="ImpactDemiPrecoce" list="[{file:'rsc/drive/4-Semis/d-ChoixDeLaDensite/ImpactDemiPrecoce'}]"    size="256px" extension="png"></photos>
```

The result is OK, except that I end up with an extraneous did tag within the photos tag replacement.
I'm stuck with this, I really dont know where it comes from.

Any one can help?

[image]

[edit 1] Those div do not come from the option text div. Here is a version with optional text provided and the related screen shot.

```
<photos photoid="ImpactPrecoce"
        list="[
            {file:'rsc/drive/4-Semis/d-ChoixDeLaDensite/ImpactPrecoce', text:'first'},
            {file:'rsc/drive/4-Semis/d-ChoixDeLaDensite/ImpactDemiPrecoce', text:'second'}
        ]"
    size="256px"
    extension="png"></photos>
```

See screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unclosed div at the end of your block (which should be the closing tag), the browser closes it automatically, as well as the parent one. So two last lines:

```
    </div>\n\
<div>'
```

should be:

```
    </div>\n\
</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it:

```
        </div>\n\
    <div>' <!-- this one was extraneous -->
};
```

Comment: Yup, wrote you about a minute ago.

Comment: Our answers have faced a race condition huh, gave your the answer. Thanks!@Shomz